# Symfony form that enters data in 2nd entity

Tags: php, symfony

I have multiple entities, but I need to use my Goeder and Bestelregel entities for this. I need to build a form for Bestelregel, but it needs to fill in data for Goeder at the same time. With EntityType I can get the data from Goeder, but I can not fill it in. But now I am stuck and don't know what to do. Can anyone help me out?

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

    class BestelregelType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('id', integerType::class);
            $builder->add('bestelhoeveelheid', integerType::class); 
            $builder->add('bestelling', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Goeder',
                'choice_label' => 'bestelordernummer',
                ));
            $builder->add('artikel', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Artikel',
                'choice_label' => 'artikelnummer',
                ));

        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Bestelregel',
            ));
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Cheers

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: `EntityType` is a special type of ChoiceType` (select field), while you want a sub form for `Goeder` entity. It seems that you want to use `GoederType` instead of `EntityType`.

Comment: Okay that is very helpfull, but what extension do I have to use at the beginnening or something at the end as well?

Comment: what exactly is the issue ?  is it not rendering your form correctly,   or is it just not persisting the data correctly ?

Comment: also, just a tip for the future,  use English classnames for entities etc, this will make it easier to understand the code, for those who dont speak Dutch

Comment: I need to fill in the attribute "bestelling" and not generate it from another entity

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a form `GoederType`.

And use it like this:

```
<?php
$builder->add('goeder', GoederType::class)
```